# clickable event on QLabel in python using pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlabel

I am working in python GUI using pyqt4 library and new with signal and slots. I don't know how to put event on label name `QPLabel`. Here is my code :

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(759, 598)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        self.QPLabel = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.QPLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 420, 141, 20))
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.QPLabel, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.doSomething)
    def doSomething(self):
         print 'Label click'
```

Anybody what should I do for event on label for doing some action.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Update the following line:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.QPLabel, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.doSomething)
```

To:

```
self.QPLabel.mousePressEvent = self.doSomething
```

and add the `event` parameter to `doSomthing`

```
...
def doSomething(self, event):
...
```

Answer (score 3):

`QLabel` doesn't have a signal `clicked`, so you can do one of the following:

A) Derive a custom class from `QLabel` implementing handlers for mouse events.

B) Implement the event handlers in `Ui_Form`, using standard `QLabels` and install the form as an event filter for the labels (`self.QPLabel.installEventFilter (self)`).