# clickable event on QLabel in python using pythonqt

Tags: python, qt, pythonqt

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232705/clickable-event-on-qlabel-in-python-using-pyqt4) and wanted to comment on [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22234720/5494061) with another question. So i want to make a label clickable in Teamspeak 3 using [my script](https://github.com/Bluscream/betterServerBrowser/blob/master/plugins/pyTSon/scripts/serverBrowser.py#L150) for [pyTson](https://github.com/pathmann/pyTSon/)

`python
07.11.2016 14:16:48 pyTSon.PluginHost.onMenuItemEvent   Error   Error calling onMenuItemEvent of python plugin Better Server Browser: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/blusc_000/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\ts3plugin.py", line 337, in onMenuItemEvent
    plugin.onMenuItemEvent(schid, atype, locid, selectedItemID)
  File "C:/Users/blusc_000/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\serverBrowser.py", line 62, in onMenuItemEvent
    self.dlg = ServersDialog(self)
  File "C:/Users/blusc_000/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\serverBrowser.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.setupList()
  File "C:/Users/blusc_000/AppData/Roaming/TS3Client/plugins/pyTSon/scripts\serverBrowser.py", line 153, in setupList
    self.pageLabel.mousePressEvent = self.on_pageLabel_clicked
AttributeError: Slot 'mousePressEvent' can not be overwritten on QLabel object`

Comment: I was fighting with this lately. The link provided by Blus cream below is a good starting point, but I had to fight some additional details. Ask a more specific question and I'm confident that I or someone else can help you.

Comment: I found [this](http://popdevelop.com/2010/05/an-example-on-how-to-make-qlabel-clickable/) and will try it later on if nothing else works.